# Is it possible to #define a class in Java?

Tags: java, class, preprocessor

I am using `ProGAL` package. There are two different classes, `ProGAL.geom2d.Point` and `ProGAL.geom3d.Point`. Both are referred as `Point`. When I import one, I only can use the other by typing the full path. For instance:

```
import ProGAL.geom3d.Point;
//...
Point pointIn3D = new Point(1,2,3);
ProGAL.geom2d.Point pointIn2D = new ProGAL.geom2d.Point(4,5);
```

I want to use something like

```
#define ProGAL.geom3d.Point point3d 
#define ProGAL.geom2d.Point point2d
```

Just like in C++. Is it possible with Java?

Usage would be like:

```
point3d pointIn3D = new point3d(1,2,3);
point2d pointIn2D = new point2d(1,2,3);
```

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately Java doesn't even have `typedef`s, let alone `#define`.

Comment: @lpratlong ha, jinx! Were you also in the same boat of just wanting to write "No" but needing to meet the minimum char requirements?

Comment: So, best call for me is to create a class and encapsulate the classes into it.

Comment: A `#define` simply creates a "replacement variable".  That is, anywhere that the first value occurs, the second will textually replace it, prior to compilation.  That said, I'm not sure you can `#define` a symbol containing a `.` character.  And certainly not in Java.

Comment: Could someone just write it as an answer so I could accept? :)

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı - you can do that yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible as there are no `#typedef` or `#define` in Java (no preparser). You could try writing another class to encapsulate the one you want to rename or just have lots of code commments.

I do want to note that I don't think that you should try to change the name of the class. It has its name for a reason. If you are going to use it within another class it is really useful for a person to know the actual class that they are working with. **This** I think is good read/usability. I don't think its good to put smoke screens where ones don't need to exist. The name is descriptive enough.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible since Java does not allow precompilation instruction.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *no*. As stated in [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/simple-142616.html) link, `typedef` and `#define` keywords are accepted as complications and removed in Java because they reduce readibility of the code.

Comment: you should accept you own answer :) also see my edit

Comment: I can accept it in 2 days :) Your edit is really helpful. Your answer is the one to be accepted, sir

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı From what I've heard, it *is* possible to have `#define` and run the code through a C preprocessor, but that's probably more hassle than it's worth